# XPages - Client side code to set viewScope value?

Tags: xpages

I have one button and on click of that button i have client side code to set `viewScope` value:

```
  var val = 'TEST_VALUE';
  "#{javascript: viewScope.testVal = " + val + "}"
```

and on server side of that button I am trying to get viewScope value:

```
print("ViewScope val " + viewScope.testVal);
```

Instead of variable value, variable name is getting stored in `ViewScope`.

Comment: You cant set ServerSideVariable that easy check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943985/xpages-how-to-set-a-scope-variable-from-client-side-javascript

Answer (score 5):

SSJS in a CSJS is computed on the server when the page is being rendered and the SSJS replaced with the result. So you're CSJS is not running SSJS. A browser cannot, by it's very nature of being a client, run server-side code. So you can include the result of SSJS in a piece of CSJS, but it will not have values updated since the last time that SSJS was recalculated on the server and passed to the browser.

You cannot update a viewScope variable via CSJS(Client Side JS), because the viewScope variable is only held on the server. It's a server-side Map, not a client-side browser cookie. So it can only be updated by server-side code or a post to run server-side code.

If you're wanting to update a viewScope variable with content from CSJS, you'll need to update a hidden input with the value, bind that hidden input to the viewScope variable and run a partial refresh to post the content of the hidden input to the server. If it's elsewhere on the page, just use SSJS to access the component / datasource and avoid the CSJS, but it's unclear what your use case is.

Comment: This is the sort of use case that the JSON-RPC component was designed for: letting the browser tell the server to do something, without all the overhead of posting the entire form and triggering a partial/full refresh.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. Paul: I have one doubt as you said "You cannot update a viewScope variable via CSJS" But if i do something like this #{javascript: var val = 'TEST_VAL'; viewScope.put('testVal', val )} on client side and keep server option of button as no update then I can update viewScope variable, the problem is if I set server option to Full or Partial update it throws client side error.

Comment: I would not be surprised if that does set the viewScope variable, but I'd be interested to know when it sets the viewScope variable. My understanding is that it would be set when the SSJS is evaluated, so when the CSJS is being written to the browser before the page is presented to the user, rather than when the button is clicked. That would also correlate with it working with no update.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers Please have a look on below code      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
 <xp:button value="Set ViewScope" id="button3">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
   refreshMode="norefresh">
   <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript: var val = 'TEST_VAL'; viewScope.put('testVal', val )}]]></xp:this.script>
   <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("ViewScope val " + viewScope.testVal);}]]></xp:this.action>
  </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:button> 
</xp:view>
  It would be great help If you can explain me above code.

Comment: Have you run the test and looked at the HTML source for this code? Please look at the CSJS onclick function. As I said in my last comment, the SSJS in xp:this.script is computed when the page is loaded and the result, "@none", is passed to the browser. As I say, you cannot run SSJS in a browser. When the button is clicked a post is made but no change is made to the browser because refreshMode="norefresh". The print statement is done on the browser, but *only* because it was run *before* the page was passed to the browser. As Tim says JSON-RPC would be a way to go.

Comment: Perhaps this blog post will make things clearer http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-calling-client-side-javascript-from-server-side-javascript/