# How to store values added to a listbox client side to sessionScope

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, xpages

I have a listbox that is populated with options client side and I need to store the values in this listbox to a sessionScope.

This is my listbox

```
<xp:listBox id="listBox1"></xp:listBox>
```

This is the jquery I use to populate the listbox

```
$("[id$='listBox1']").append("<option value='"+ ret + "'>" + ret + "</option>")
```

This is the button I have to save the listbox into sessionScope

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.pending = getComponent("listBox1").getValue()}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

for some reason the listbox values is not saved to my sessionScope. if I pre populate the listbox in DDE it works but that is not what I want.

- I have also tried to bind the listBox to a data source without any luck
- I have also tried to select the values before I click the button

how can I get the value i populated client side into my sessionScope.

Full Code to paste into a new Xpage, (you need jquery or bootstrap theme)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="d" formName="Main"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:button value="ADD TO LISTBOX" id="button2">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var ret = "Testin"
$("[id$='listBox1']").append("<option value='"+ ret + "'>" + ret + "</option>")]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:listBox id="listBox1" value="#{sessionScope.pending}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete"></xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:listBox>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="save" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.pending = getComponent("listBox1").getValue()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{sessionScope.pending}"></xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: You tried to bind it, didn't you? `value="#{sessionScope.pending}"` should work.

Comment: you mean I should bind the listbox to your suggestion? what should I do in my button then?

Comment: Nothing, just do a full refresh. values selected in listBox1 will be POSTed to model and binded.

Comment: have you tried it? I could not get it to work, I updated my post with the complete xpage.

Comment: When you manipulate HTML locally, the server side tree doesn't know anything about it. On a refresh the values would be gone. You need a different approach.

Comment: yes. but it is inconsistent in the way that it works for inputboxes but not combo/list boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work as designed:

```
<xp:listBox
    id="listBox1"
    value="#{sessionScope.pending}">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="A"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="B"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:listBox>
<xp:button
    value="OK"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

I know, it does not populate values with JQuery, but it should not make a difference...

Disclaimer: There might be a problem with model update - if the component submits values not defined via sources - `<xp:selectItem>`. This usually happens with comboboxes - submitted values must match any value generated by XPage.

I suppose there is a choice to pre populate listbox options natively. If not, try a workaround:

You can use CSJS to put selected value into hidden input binded to sessionScope. That one will be submited. Notice the binding is moved from `listBox1` to `inputHiden1`.

```
<xp:button
    value="Refresh"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="inputHidden1">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var lb = dojo.byId("#{id:listBox1}");
var hi = dojo.byId("#{id:inputHidden1}");
hi.value = lb.options[lb.selectedIndex].innerHTML;]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:inputHidden
    id="inputHidden1"
    value="#{sessionScope.pending}">
</xp:inputHidden>
```

Script copying value from listbox to hidden input can be run in onChange of listBox to avoid the need of button click.

See also: [XPages - Client side code to set viewScope value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815183/xpages-client-side-code-to-set-viewscope-value/16818467#16818467)

Comment: as I mentioned in my post I already know it is working if I pre populate the listbox in DDE. unfortunately this is not an option in my case

Comment: you won't get component value that way, as I stated in disclaimer

Comment: I do not understand your solution : You can use CSJS to put selected value into hidden edit binded to sessionScope. That one will be submited.

Comment: I just saw your new code above. I still cannot get it to work. and another problem with this approach is that the scope must no be a single value, it must be stored as a list of values in scope so that I can loop them.

Comment: I have tested it, it submits values. Multiselect: what is binded is string, content of input text. You need to `@Explode` it before processing.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a simple RPC call.

1. Add a RPC in your page, in this example I will consider `myRPC` as the service name.
2. Define a function for this RPC that takes as input the array of values. The function just set this array in a **sessionScope** variable. In this example I name the function `setScopeVariable`;
3. After your **client side code** that build the values for your listbox, just call this RPC function. Here `listBoxValues` is an array containing the list of values :
       myRPC.setScopeVariable(listBoxValues);
4. The sessionScope is now set to the right value.

By doing so you will need no hidden input, and no refresh on your page in order to set the sessionScope.