# How to pass variable from CSJS to SSJS in read mode

Tags: xpages

I want to be able to prompt the user for a comment and then be able to send this variable comment in an email.  However, I'm unable to pass that variable from CSJS to SSJS.  My document is in read mode.

Here is a sample button code where I can't seem to pass my comment.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

```
<xp:panel readonly="false">
    <xp:inputHidden id="inputHidden1" value="#{viewScope.tester}">
    </xp:inputHidden>
</xp:panel>

<xp:button value="Reject" id="button7" style="margin-right:5.0px"
save="false">

<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:actionGroup>

            <xp:executeScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("status", "0"); 
doc.save();
database.updateFTIndex(false);

var comment = viewScope.tester; /* HOW DO I GET COMMENT FROM CSJS TO HERE */

var ndoc = database.createDocument();
ndoc.appendItemValue("from", "tome@somewhere.com");
ndoc.appendItemValue("SendTo", "someone@somewhere.com);
ndoc.appendItemValue("subject", "My Subject");
var rti:NotesRichTextItem = ndoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
rti.appendText("Reason:" + comment + "\n\n");
ndoc.send()

}]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeScript>
            <xp:openPage name="/mainpage.xsp"></xp:openPage>
        </xp:actionGroup>
    </xp:this.action>

    <xp:this.script>
        <xp:executeClientScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
var comment = XSP.prompt("Please enter a comment:");


XSP.getElementById("#{id:inputHidden1}").value = comment;


/*
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:computedField1}", 
{
params:{"para1":"1", "para2":"2"}
});

*/

]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeClientScript>
    </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XSP.prompt` will use the default browser prompt window. You will have limited functionality from it and, in my opinion, not a great user experience. I would recommend having your reject button open an XPages Extension Library dialog with an Edit Box to enter the comment. Bind the Edit Box to a `requestScope` variable - you won't need the value after the dialog closes, so you would need it at a higher scope level. In the "OK" button of the dialog run your SSJS and use the SSJS `hide()` method of the Dialog component to close the dialog, adding a parameter for a component on the page if you need to partially refresh it.

Comment: At first, it did not work for me.  It turned out that because I had it inside a panel with the rest of the other controls, it did not work. Once I took it out of the panel and had it on it's own, it worked like a charm.  I liked that option better because It allowed me to design my own dialog instead of being dependent on the prompt functionality.   Thanks for the response and suggestion. That worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind that field to your document (in read mode). Bind it to `viewScope` or `requestScope` variable.

Also, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943985/xpages-how-to-set-a-scope-variable-from-client-side-javascript/15948134#15948134) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I saw that post before and tried it and it didn't work.


    <xp:inputHidden id="inputHidden1" value="#{requestScope.tester}">
  </xp:inputHidden>

In then I call it from SSJS 
    var comment = requestScope.tester;

Comment: So after simplifying my code, it turns out that my button and my hidden input was not functioning because they were inside a panel with the rest of the other control elements.  Once I took my button and hidden input out of the panel and had them on their own, it worked fine.  So it seems that if you are going to use this method, you just need to make sure it's not inside the same panel.  Anyway, this ended up working but I ended up using the Extension Library as per Paul's suggestion.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in the past, I have used CSS to hide the input fields and buttons.  The client-side script is defined separately from the button actions.

```
<xp:text escape="false"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[
    <script>

    function promptBox(){
        // ... do whatever to get the data input into
        // XSP.getElementById("#{id:inputText1}").value 
        // OR if using JQuery $('.tester).val()

        // then click hidden Save button
        $('.reject').click()
        // OR
        XSP.getElementById("#{id:button1}").click()
    }
    </script>
]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>

<!-- hide the input field with CSS -->
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{viewScope.tester}"
    defaultValue="#{viewScope.tester}"
    styleClass="tester hidden">
</xp:inputText>

<!-- hide the button with CSS -->
<xp:button
    value="Reject"
    styleClass="reject hidden"
    id="button1">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:actionGroup>

            <xp:executeScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("status", "0"); 
doc.save();
database.updateFTIndex(false);

var comment = viewScope.tester; /* scoped variable already set */

var ndoc = database.createDocument();
ndoc.appendItemValue("from", "tome@somewhere.com");
ndoc.appendItemValue("SendTo", "someone@somewhere.com);
ndoc.appendItemValue("subject", "My Subject");
var rti:NotesRichTextItem = ndoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
rti.appendText("Reason:" + comment + "\n\n");
ndoc.send()

}]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeScript>
            <xp:openPage name="/mainpage.xsp"></xp:openPage>
        </xp:actionGroup>
</xp:button>

<!-- use link for button - style it with CSS -->
<a href="javascript:promptBox()"  class="btn btn-success">Reject</a>
```

I do not like having both client-side and server-side scripts bound to the same button, the execution order of the code is not easily managed.  There are other ways to combine these client side fields and server side scripts, but this is a simple demonstration.